# How a variable can have two values at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-debugging

I guess with what I'm going to write I should first clarify, it's not something I would like to achieve. It is something that happened to me and I am trying understand how it is possible, so I can fix it. So here we go...

I'm using C#, .Net 4.0. The code is biggish, too big to past it all here but I try to explain what happens in hope that there is somebody knowledgeable who will have some thoughts.

In my call stack I have a series of generic methods and I have noticed that although the value should be just passed from one to the other it is changing. Ok, that was my first impression. Later I managed to isolate one problematic method in which when I stop I can see two different values for the same property of an object.

```
public class Sample : BaseClass, ISomeInterface
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public new Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

What may be significant that both BaseClass and ISomeINterface define

```
public Guid Id
```

so now, when I stop in that generic method and watch variable *data* of *Sample* type i can expand its properties and see the first value of *Id*. But when I watch *data.Id* it shows different value. Have a look for yourself.

(Here was a picture which I cannot post due to a negligible reputation. Sorry)

Edit: I pushed it there http://picturepush.com/public/7307446

Would any body out there know what is the difference in how those values in the *Watch* window are obtained? What is the difference? I tried many different approaches, casting, using reflection but always I get the value the same as when you watch *data.Id* and ironically, the correct value, the one I expect is the other, elusive one.

Oh, and no, it is not a homework ;)

Comment: Upload the picture to somewhere else, please.

Comment: What does the BaseClass look like? When you check to see the value is the Sample class instance cast as a Sample Class or a BaseClass?

Comment: Is the property decorated with the DebuggerDisplayAttribute? You could display a different value to what your seeing when you expand the object in the debugger.

Comment: Picture uploaded [link](http://picturepush.com/public/7307446)
I have tried casting to all possible types to no avail, the value is always the same

The property is not decorated with the DebuggigerDisplayAttribute

But going through the code again I have noticed that ValueInjector is used earlier to copy the values from a different object. Could it be side effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new` keyword is hiding the base class member.

Set the `Id` property in `BaseClass` to virtual:

```
public class BaseClass : ISomeInterface
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

And override it in `Sample`:

```
public class Sample : BaseClass, ISomeInterface
{
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That has solved it. I can understand how hiding can be confusing for developers but it is there for a reason, sometimes you need to define  (or redefine) a property. But here it looks like debugger/compiler/.Net_framework were being confused too but the 'feature' of the language ;)

Answer (score 3):

When you're defining Id in both the base class and actual class, the second definition isn't overriding the first but **hiding** it. This means that the Sample class actually contains both definitions and it depends on the static type of the variable which you access.

Hence:

```
Sample s = new Sample();
BaseClass b = (BaseClass)s;
s.Id != b.Id;
```

This is generally not what you want and can lead to quite strange behavior, as you've already found out :)

Simple compileable example that demonstrates this:

```
class A {
    public int val = 5;

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A a = (A)b;
        Console.WriteLine(a.val); // 5
        Console.WriteLine(b.val); // 10
    }
}

class B : A {
    public int val = 10;
}
```

If you already have this mess and can't fix it correctly, you can cast the static type to whatever version you want to access.

Comment: I thought about that and have tried casting to all the types in the hierarchy to no avail. In your example the two variables are clearly of two different types. Please see the image I have uploaded, I'm talking about one variable of one type at the same moment in time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't define the `Id` property in the `Sample` class.  Just inherit it from `BaseClass`.  The above code should be producing compiler warnings that Sample.Id is hiding BaseClass.Id

Comment: There is new before that Id. I need to have it there to be able to decorate it with attributes which are not in the base class.

Comment: You're right. I missed the `new` keyword.  This is the source of your problem, though.  If you're code has a reference of type `BaseClass` you'll see the Id defined in the BaseClass.  If the reference is of type `Sample`, you'll see the new one.  If you can't modify the base class then you'll need to ensure that you're dealing with a reference of type `Sample` whenever you you use it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Sure thing hiding was source of the problem, but the concept as such is well know (to me). The real issue, and the source of confusion was why was it happening only in one method, and why debugger was showing two values at the same time. Anyway, that is now solved. Overriding rather than hiding helped.